# Image Detect App Which upload dynamiclly from admin app in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to make an app for my university project that upload image from the Admin App to the server &  In the User App User Scan Image From the Camera & check whether the image exists on the server or not & get the image description which is also uploaded from the admin App.

I found some plugins in a flutter

## [google_mlkit_object_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_object_detection)

## [flutter_tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tflite)

Comment: First detect user face using google_mlkit_face_detection: ^0.5.0 - https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection. And then if face is detected, then save the image locally and pass it to image verification API

Comment: there's no need for user face detection. i want to Upload image from the admin app & if user selects something similar image from its gallery which exists in server or not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.